# VBA reusable loops function

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint

I am using several times for each and for loop in powerpoint vba, to loop all the slides and shapes. for example,

For i = Activepresentation.slides(i).count
next i

For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
next i

Dim sld as slide
Dim shp as shape
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each shp in sld.shapes
next sld
next shp

Is there a way to create a reusable function for these loops? so that, it can be called, whenever required.

Thank you very much.

Thanks and Regards,
Balu.

Comment: in which language is this? Add this to your tag or question.

Comment: That code isn't valid C++, it would have to be `class a* obj = new b;` to even compile

Comment: show real code and create a [MRE].

Comment: @UnholySheep it could be if there wasn't a missing `*`.  But in any case, a badly formed question.

Comment: or there is no inheritance relationship between the two but a has a ctor that takes a b * argument.

Comment: Please add a minimal example. Show the relationship between class a and class b. You don't need to show 50 lines of code but just enough to see the relationship and constructors.

Comment: Please help with my edited question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If i get you write - you try to create a class obj. with operator new. 
but youre code is not quite right. it is more like:
**class a * obj = new a();**
It is means that you get some memory and build there class a OBJ with some parametrs from youre class a;
in class a youll need something "constructor" like:
**a(){this->param = xx;this->param = xxx};**

Answer (score 0):

If you claim that `class a* obj = new b`, then class `b` must be a derived type from class a.

```
class a {};
class b : public a {};
```

You are allocating space for the contents of the class and calling the constructor using `operator new`. Because a class b is a type of class a, you can request a pointer to class a from an allocated class b, because class b is a class a.